# Вот все говорят MVP MVC MVVP под Android, для чего они?

Tags: java, android

Вот все говорят MVP MVC MVVP под Android, для чего они?

Я не пользовался таким подходом к программированию, поэтому не пойму зачем это все делать.
 Говорят что это упрощяет читабельность кода. Но все же.  Приходиться писать код в 10 раз больше.

Какой реальный плюс данного паттерна? Возможно мое мышление немного не такое как у вас. Просто для меня допустим библиотека Picasso, упрощяет реально жизнь разработчика сама грузит и устанавливает картинку за 2-6 строчек кода.

Что такого может дать MVP MVC я не понимаю....Объясните кто нить. Заблудился в гугле

Comment: вы пишите тесты на свой код? насколько большие у вас приложения?

Comment: Гугл не поможет, здесь необходим опыт, причем в реальной работе, а если вы не работаете и даже не в активном поиске (работы :) ), то останетесь в непонимании очень многого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как минимум MVC-подходом (или MVVM, если используете data binding) вы пользовались непременно, если вам удалось хоть что то вывести на экран - этот паттерн используется в Android "по умолчанию" (xml-разметка - V, activity - C, то, что отображается (данные) - M). То, что вы не осознаете, какие паттерны вы применяете, не говорит о том, что они не применяются.

Приемущества MVVM и биндинга очевидны при малейшем [проявлении интереса](https://www.google.ru/search?&q=data+binding+android) к этому паттерну. Прочие паттерны более "узкоспециализированы" и необходимость их применения исходит из решаемых ими задач, то есть если вы не видите (пока) приемуществ MVP, MVI или там MVVM, то для вас их нет и думать об этом вам не надо. Когда появится проблема, потребуются решения, придет понимание.